# Sorting based on computed property (NDWI)

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, sorting

I am trying to sort a series of sentinel 2 images based on their average NDWI in the google earth engine. But nothing I do in sorting seems to work. Here I ll show what i tried:

's2_ndwi_mean' is a list of objects with 2 properties:

- 'NDWI' which is the average mean NDWI
- 'system:time_start' which is the time the image was taken.

This variable forms the starting point for this example.

Sorting a single dimensional array works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var ndwi_test = ee.Number(ee.Dictionary(s2_ndwi_mean.get(i)).get('NDWI')).float()
    ndwi_array.push(ndwi_test)
}

ndwi_array= ee.Array(ndwi_array).sort()
```

However sorting a list of objects based on their property does not seem to work. I tried a similar approach to this:

```
cars = [
    {
        name: "Honda",
        speed: 80
    },

    {
        name: "BMW",
        speed: 180
    },
]


cars.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.speed - b.speed;
})
```

But I cannot get this to work for earth engine list types.

Then i tried sorting a two dimensional array instead of a list. This is how it should work for a Javascript Array. But this seemed impossible for an earth engine array:

```
var a = [[12, 'AAA'], [58, 'BBB'], [28, 'CCC'],[18, 'DDD']];

a.sort(sortFunction);

function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what the approach should be. Sorting a list of images based on computed average NDWI's?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, 's2_ndwi_mean' is a list of objects `ee.Image` with a property called 'NDWI' which is the average mean NDWI.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(s2_ndwi_mean)
var sorted_asc = collection.sort('NDWI')
var sorted_desc = collection.sort('NDWI', false)
```

Comment: I know it's simple, but that's what I think the question is asking

Comment: Thanks, the question was indeed solved by making an Imagecollection from the list and having NDWI as a meta property.